# Linux files permissions denied on log files

Tags: linux, file-permissions, debian-jessie, ossec, nxlog

I have installed `nxlog` to send my logs to a graylog server. It works fine, but I have a denied permission on the logs of my HIDS Ossec.

My process `nxlog` (launched by collector-sidecar) run as root :

```
# ps -ef | grep collector
root      1869     1  0 13:23 ?        00:00:03 /usr/bin/graylog-collector-sidecar
root      1905  1869  0 13:23 ?        00:00:29 /usr/bin/nxlog -f -c /etc/graylog/collector-sidecar/generated/nxlog.conf
```

In the `nxlog.conf`, I have :

```
User root
Group adm
```

The rights on the OSSEC logs are as follow (`ossec:ossec` for `/var/ossec/logs`):

```
# namei -l /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log
f: /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /
drwxr-xr-x root  root  var
dr-xr-x--- root  ossec ossec
drwxr-x--- ossec ossec logs
-rw-r--r-- root  ossec active-responses.log
```

So, the user `ossec` and the members of the group `OSSEC` can read this file (I think).

I added the root to the group ossec :

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groupes=0(root),1005(ossec)
```

I tested with a reboot of my server but I read in the logs of nxlog :

```
ERROR apr_stat failed on file /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log;Permission denied
```

When I chown to `root` the directory `/var/ossec/logs` to have :

```
# namei -l /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log
f: /var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log
drwxr-xr-x root root  /
drwxr-xr-x root root  var
dr-xr-x--- root ossec ossec
drwxr-x--- root ossec logs
-rw-r--r-- root ossec active-responses.log
```

So, why when I put `root` to the `ossec` group, my `nxlog` process can't read this file ?

Comment: OSSEC and ossec are different groups.

Comment: sorry, problem of typo. I confirm the group ossec and not OSSEC

Answer (score -1):

Can you try removing `User root` from your `nxlog.conf`? It will be still running as `root`. Afair there was a bug with this in the CE.